# PHP Foreach Loop Adding Blank MySQL Entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form with checkboxes that I am passing to PHP in an array.  I am then using a Foreach loop to insert data from the form into a MySQL database.  The data is getting entered, but it is also adding in a blank entry.  I have attempted to verify that the value is not blank but am still not able to get it to not put in blank data.

FORM:

```
<form action="work.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="MOC" /> MOC<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="Spectrum" /> Spectrum<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="Calls" /> Calls<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="IPMon" /> IPMon<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="SEV 1/2" /> SEV 1/2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="LBC" /> LBC<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="Email Queue" /> Email Queue<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="NOC Inbox" /> NOC Inbox<br />
<label>Special Projects:</label><input type="text" name="special" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(ISSET($_POST['work'])){
    foreach($_POST['work'] as $work){
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Working (wuid, task) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$work."')");
    }
}
```

MySQL Data:

```
wuid    task    id
tduran          37
tduran  IPMon   36
tduran  Calls   35
```

The $username variable is pulled from an LDAP authentication so doesn't change.  The issue is with $work.  I've printed out the array and variables multiple times, but can't get it to display the blank content.  Been pulling my hair out on this.  Hopefully

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['work']);` give you? And you might want to switch to prepared statements to close the sql injection hole you have now.

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Calls" [1]=> string(7) "SEV 1/2" [2]=> string(3) "LBC" }

I get the above when selecting on Calls, SEV 1/2, and LBC.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the description of above mentioned issue you have defined HTML array for checkbox element.In server side we get values of only those checkboxes which are checked using $_POST['work '] which will be an array.

So for getting values of all checkboxes you need to check all the checkboxes

You will get resultant array of values for checked checkboxes through $_POST['work'].